# To check whether a character in a variable is an alphabet, digit, or special character in dart

Tags: dart

Write a dart program to check whether a character
in a variable is an alphabet, digit, or special character in dart.
Test Data :
@
Expected Output :
This is a special character.

Test Data :
@
Expected Output :
This is a special character.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. Please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?
If you don't know how to start, tutorials and text books would be a better choice. See also [ask].